# Prove that polynomial $p(x)$ od degree $n$ is equal to $cP_{n}(x)$, where $P_{n}(x)$ is Legendre polynomial.

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, orthogonality, legendre-polynomials

This is the problem $5$ from chapter $45$ on properties of Legendre polynomials from Simmons book "Differential Equations with Applications and Historical Notes".

If $p(x)$ is a polynomial of degree $n ≥ 1$ such that

$$\int_{-1}^{1} x^{k}p(x) dx = 0 \\ \text{for} \ k=0,1,2,\cdots,n-1$$

Show that $p(x)=cP_{n}(x)$ for some constant $c$

I gave it go, trying to use properties of even and odd function. I suspect that I have to use orthogonality of Legendre polynomials. Sadly I am stuck and have no idea what to do. I was also thinking about using induction out of despretation but that seems "wrong" for me in this case.

Comment: There are many (equivalent) definitions of Legendre polynomials. What is yours?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you should prove that
$$\int_{-1}^1 x^k P_n(x)\ \mathrm dx=0$$
for all $0\le k<n$. Then, notice instead that
$$\int_{-1}^1 x^n P_n(x)\ \mathrm dx\neq0$$
and call $C$ that value. Now, define your $c$ as
$$c:=\frac1C\int_{-1}^1 x^n p(x)\ \mathrm dx$$

You proved that, for any $0\le k\le n$, it holds
$$\int_{-1}^1 x^k (p(x)-cP_n(x))\ \mathrm dx=0$$
but now, by linearity, for ANY polinomial $q$ of degree $\le n$ it holds
$$\int_{-1}^1 q(x) (p(x)-cP_n(x))\ \mathrm dx=0$$
But now, $p(x)-cP_n(x)$ is a polynomial of degree $\le n$, and so
$$\int_{-1}^1 (p(x)-cP_n(x))^2\ \mathrm dx=0$$
and the only possibility is $p(x)-cP_n(x)=0$.

Comment: In the Euclidean space $\Bbb R_n[X],$ the orthogonal of the hyperplane generated by $1,x,\dots,x^{n-1}$ is obviously a line, but an answer should prove that this line is precisely the one generated by $P_n.$ For this, the OP has to give us his definition of $P_n,$ as previously asked by comment.

Comment: The Legendre polynomials are the solutions to $(1-x^2)y''-2xy'+n(n+1)y = 0$. They are also given by Rodrigues’ formula.

Comment: @Glitterfrost : So you get eigenfunctions to $-((1-x^2)y')'=\lambda y$ for eigenvalues $\lambda y=n(n+1)$. Now apply the inherent orthogonality for such eigenfunctions. Then contemplate how they could be a basis for the polynomial space.